# Average, minimum, maximum

Tags: java

so in my program is where the user enters list of numbers one at a time, and when I would end the list numbers with the "end" statement which is set to -1, and once I do that I get my average, and maximum, and minimum, my problem is that when I do get the  minimum output it would be -1 everytime, I'm having trouble to remove the -1 from the array, any ideas???

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner to user scanner tool

public class Average { //creating public class

    public static void main(String[]args) { //creating public static main

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //creating scanner input to grab user input

        System.out.println("Please enter a list of numbers, entering -1 to end the list: ");

        double[] numbers = new double[20]; //creating 20 count array
        double sum = 0; 
        int count = 0;
        double average;
        int end = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++) {

            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();

            if(numbers[i]== end) {

             break;

            }
            sum+= numbers[i];
            count++;
        }    
        // gets average from user input of numbers
        average = sum/count;
        System.out.println("Average is: " + average);
        double max = maxim(numbers);
        System.out.println("Max: " + max);
        double min = minim(numbers);
        System.out.println("Min: " + min);

    }

//method for finding out maximum number from user input

    public static double maxim(double[] array) {

        double maxNum = array[0];
        for(int i = 1; i<array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] > maxNum) {
                maxNum = array[i];
            }
        }
     return maxNum; 
    }
 //method for finding out minimum number from user input   

    public static double minim(double[] array) {

        double minNum = array[0];
        for(int i = 1; i<array.length; i++) {
               if(array[i] < minNum && array[i]!=-1) {
                minNum = array[i];
            }

        }
     return minNum; 
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need any array to do that. Just compute the min and the max at each iteration, just like you're doing with sum and count, by comparing the new number with the previous min/max. If you really want to keep it that way, just don't store -1 in the array, instead of trying to remove it. Your maxim and minim methods should take the count as argument, and only take into account the `count`first elements of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to docouple part of code that responsible for reading user input from code that compute statistics. And for remove -1 from resulting array you need simple don't put this value to result. When user input random number first check if it is not -1, and after that put it in result. Something like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Average {  

    public static void main(String[]args) { //creating public static main
        double[] numbers = readInputNumbers();
        System.out.println("Average is: " + average(numbers));
        System.out.println("Max: " + max(numbers));
        System.out.println("Min: " + min(numbers));
    }

    public double[] readInputNumbers() {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //creating scanner input to grab user input
      System.out.println("Please enter a list of numbers, entering -1 to end the list: ");
      double[] numbers = new double[20];
      final int endInput = -1;
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
          System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
          double nextNumber = input.nextDouble();
          if(nextNumber == endInput) {
              break;
          } else {
              numbers[i] = nextNumber;
          }
      }
      return numbers;   
  }

    public static double max(double[] array) {
        double maxNum = array[0];
        for(int i = 1; i<array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] > maxNum) {
                maxNum = array[i];
            }
        }
     return maxNum; 
    }

    public static double min(double[] array) {
        double minNum = array[0];
        for(int i = 1; i<array.length; i++) {
               if(array[i] < minNum && array[i]!=-1) {
                minNum = array[i];
            }

        }
     return minNum; 
    }

    public static double average(double[] numbers) {
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + numbers[i];
        }
        return sum / numbers.length; 
    }

}
```

In jdk since 8 version your could be simplify this task like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.stream.*; 

public class Average {  

    public static void main(String[]args) { //creating public static main
        double[] numbers = readInputNumbers();
        DoubleSummaryStatistics statistics = DoubleStream.of(numbers).summaryStatistics();
        System.out.println("Average is: " + statistics.getAverage()));
        System.out.println("Max: " + statistics.getMax());
        System.out.println("Min: " + statistics.getMin());
    }

    public double[] readInputNumbers() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //creating scanner input to grab user input
        System.out.println("Please enter a list of numbers, entering -1 to end the list: ");
        double[] numbers = new double[20];
        final int endInput = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            double nextNumber = input.nextDouble();
            if(nextNumber == endInput) {
                break;
            } else {
                numbers[i] = nextNumber;
            }
        }
        return numbers;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the input into a temp variables and store it in the array only if it isn't the end flag (`-1`). E.g.:

```
for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++) {

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double temp = input.nextDouble();

    if(temp == end) {
        break;
    }
    numbers[i] = temp;
    sum += numbers[i];
    count++;
}
```